# Artifactory/Jenkins Upload Spec using classifier?

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I'm looking to use the upload spec to upload artifacts to artifactory from a jenkins job.  I'd like to be able to use it to additionally attach a classifier to the artifact for if it is referenced through Maven.

Do you know if there's a way to do this?  I'd like to use the upload spec for simplicity and ideally avoid having to get my hands too dirty with Maven.

Answer (score 1):

I realised the answer to my own question.  You assign a repository layout to your repo.  For example maven-2-default.  This describes the file format and how that relates to version number, classifier etc.

Comment: classifier is available if using mvn deploy to upload to artifactory. You do have to have a maven 2 type of repository for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs) to upload or download from artifactory in a Jenkins Free Style job (simply check the Generic-Artifactory Integration) or a Jenkins Pipeline Job.

HTH,

Or

Comment: There is no classifier field in the file specs